# Typesafe ConfigFactory Load

Tags: playframework, config

I have a JSON in the conf directory of my Play application and I want to load it using the ConfigFactory:

```
 val cfg = ConfigFactory.load("myJson.json")
 val jsValue = Json.parse(cfg.root().render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise()))
```

What I notice is that there are tons of other stuff like akka... and loads more. How should I get rid of it?

I'm using Play's Json API!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard behaviour is described here:

https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior

Since there are more configuration values than you think, you can only be selective in picking the required configuration values.

Or maybe, check against reference.conf and discard those values in your output.